# XSD Files in asp.net preview data

Tags: asp.net, datatableadapters

I have created a Stored Procedure in SQL and have configured it to be used with DataTables. The stored Procedure accepts 3 variables.
1. 3635 (Int)
2. NotMeeting (AnsiString)
3. 1 (Boolean)

When i want to preview the output after inserting values into the "Preview Data" function in DataTables, i get the following error:

"Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Boolean".

I tried putting single speechmarks around '1' & double speechmarks of "1" but it makes no difference.

This works fine if i execute it in SQL Server Management Studio
(i.e.
exec dbo.EXSP_CIA_Events_Timeline_List @Ext_Acquisition_ID=3635,@CalcType='NotMeeting',@UseCompleteTasks=1
)
Any clues?

Comment: It seems that there is something wrong with you`r stored procedure, maybe @CalcType is declared as boolean inside of you`r procedure. Can you give us you`r procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are maybe using ADO.net, in which case, you don't pass 1 to the SqlParameter, you would pass an actual boolean value (e.g. true/false).

Comment: @user532104 - feel free to accept as an answer (green tick) if this worked for you.